# Kotlin onClick clear a field

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to have a field cleared before the user starts typing. When I first click on the field using the code below, it brings up the keyboard and only on second click of the field does it clear it.

I want to bring the keyboard up and clear the field.

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

        val findAcctBtn         = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.findAcctBtn)
        val phoneNumberField    = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneNumberField)

        phoneNumberField.setOnClickListener {
            phoneNumberField.getText().clear()
        }

        findAcctBtn.setOnClickListener {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: why using findViewById, you can directly use view in kotlin :)

Comment: How do you do that to this line? view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.view_transactions_btn).setOnClickListener(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to implement this behavior would be adding a `OnFocusChangeListener` to your `EditText`. Although `click` and `touch` listeners should help you clear text when the `EditText` is clicked, it doesn't prevent the situation when you have several `EditText`s in your layout placed one by one and user navigates between them using IME option button on their keyboard. Consider this example:

[image]

This layout has three `EditText`s with attribute `android:maxLines="1"`

Currently the user has just finished typing text 'First editText' in the first `EditText` and want to proceed to the next `EditText` by pressing IME button on the keyboard. If you just add click or touch listeners to the `EditText`, they won't be triggered since the user doesn't actually touch the screen and the `EditText` won't be cleared.

So instead of touch listeners I suggest to add `OnFocusChangeListener`. After doing so every time when your `EditText` gain focus (either if it's been clicked or navigated to with IME button), it will be cleared. Example:

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_text)
editText.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        (v as EditText).text.clear()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to use a boolean variable:

```
   var isFirstClick = true

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

        val findAcctBtn         = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.findAcctBtn)
        val phoneNumberField    = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneNumberField)

        phoneNumberField.setOnClickListener {
            if(isFirstClick)
                 isFirstClick = false
            else 
                phoneNumberField.text = ""
            ///other work
        }
    }
```

Or if you`d like to always clear the field you could just

```
 phoneNumberField.setOnClickListener {
             phoneNumberField.text = ""
            ///other work
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this by handling onTouchEvent and show keyboard manually

```
phoneNumberField.setOnTouchListener{ view, motionEvent ->
        phoneNumberField.setText("")
        view.post {
            val keyBoard = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            keyBoard.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        }
        false
    }
```

Comment: I get a "No value passed parameter 'ServiceClass' "

Type interence failed: fun <T: Any!> getSystemService(context: Context,serviceClass:Class<T!>):T? cannot be applied to (String)

Comment: @SebastienDesemberg you have to call context.getSystemService, this method is from context